# how to Convert UTC timestamp to some other zone timestamp and extract day,daynumber,date,month,year,time,timezone in Java

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetimeoffset

I am receiving a UTC timestamp "2021-02-11T09:00:00-07:00 --UTC" in a json Object which has to be converted to some other zone timestamp. Once converted to the desired zone timestamp  I need to extract day, day number,
date, month, year, time, timezone and store it in a map.

Kindly advise.

Comment: use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html class it has all the method you need to convert to different timezone and to get the day and month and so on then use any suitable map you like to store the data

Comment: Look into `OffsetDateTime`, `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). That shouldn’t be too hard. Make an attempt, and if doesn’t go smoothly, please ask a new question about any trouble you’re having.

Comment: The date and time in your string are at UTC offset -07:00. The trailing ` --UTC` confuses me. Is it really part of the string? Do you know whether it means something?

Comment: (Offset -7 meaning that your “UTC timestamp” could for instance originate from America/Creston or America/Phoenix time zone.)

Comment: @OleV.V. -I think it doesn't have any meaning as the info is being passed down through multiple components it is just for an indication of the timezone. Thanks for your advise. I have seen your contribution alot on this platform as I was going through others solution.:)

Comment: @justsomeone Thank you It is indeed a very helpful document.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "2021-02-11T09:00:01-07:00 --UTC";
    String timeStampCleanedUp = input.replaceFirst("\\s+--UTC", "");

    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeTmp = ZonedDateTime.parse(timeStampCleanedUp);

    //Conevert to other TimeZone, such as 'America/New_York':
    ZonedDateTime  zonedDateTime = zonedDateTimeTmp.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
    System.out.printf("Time stamp after zone time conversion: from '%s' to '%s'%n%n", zonedDateTimeTmp, zonedDateTime);

    //day, daynumber, date, month, year, time,timezone
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();

    result.put("DayOfWeek", zonedDateTime.getDayOfWeek().name()); //Day
    result.put("DayOfMonth", String.valueOf(zonedDateTime.getDayOfMonth())); //DayNumber
    result.put("Month", zonedDateTime.getMonth().name()); //Month
    result.put("Date", zonedDateTime.toLocalDate().toString()); //Date
    result.put("Month", zonedDateTime.getMonth().name()); //Month
    result.put("Year", String.valueOf(zonedDateTime.getYear())); //Year
    result.put("Time", zonedDateTime.toLocalTime().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)); //Time
    result.put("Offset", zonedDateTime.getOffset().getId()); //Offset
    result.put("TimeZone", zonedDateTime.getZone().getId()); //TimeZone

    result.keySet().stream().sorted().forEach(key -> System.out.printf("Key: '%s' => Value: '%s'%n", key, result.get(key)));
}
```

Output:

```
Time stamp after zone time conversion: from '2021-02-11T09:00:01-07:00' to '2021-02-11T11:00:01-05:00[America/New_York]'

Key: 'Date' => Value: '2021-02-11'
Key: 'DayOfMonth' => Value: '11'
Key: 'DayOfWeek' => Value: 'THURSDAY'
Key: 'Month' => Value: 'FEBRUARY'
Key: 'Offset' => Value: '-05:00'
Key: 'Time' => Value: '11:00:01'
Key: 'TimeZone' => Value: 'America/New_York'
Key: 'Year' => Value: '2021'
```

You can see Available Zone Ids by using **ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()**:

```
ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

You can read more about ZonId and ZoneOffset here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the effort you put to solve my query. Will test it soon and will get back in case of any queries.:)

Comment: Happy that you appreciate the effort. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @DigitShifter just a quick question here you have added the timezone "America/New_York" but can this be more generic in regards to various offsets. I am not sure how can I fetch a timezone out of the given offset. This code will fail if the offset changes. Kindly advise.

Comment: final List<ZoneId> timeZoneByUtc = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream().map(ZoneId::of)
        .filter(z -> z.getRules().getOffset(Instant.now()).equals(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-7)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: I tried the above code for -7 but it is a list and which one to pick.

Comment: Yes, you can set zonedDateTime with an offset instead of a zone name, see:         ZonedDateTime  zonedDateTime = zonedDateTimeTmp.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-7));

Comment: Thanks @DigitShifter. Now we will be getting the direct timezone value like PST, CST etc.. as day light savings can make diffrence if only the offset is considered.